# Table with foreign key of same entity type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Hi I've been searching around for like 40 minutes now trying to figure out how to do this and I'm not having any luck. I'm creating a forum app with ASP.NET. MVC5, and EF6. My app contains a Comment model; this is where I started running into problems. I want threads to be able to have comments(this was easy) and I also want comments to have comments(This is my problem).

Here is how my model is defined:

```
    namespace Forum.Models
    {
        public class Comment
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id {get; set;}
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}",         
             ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

            public string Content { get; set; }

            public String UserId { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("ParentComment")]
            public int ParentCommentId { get; set; }
            public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }

            public int ThreadId { get; set; }
            public virtual Thread Thread {get; set;}
         }
     }
```

This is the error I get when I try to update this table:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Comments' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "*when I try to update this table*"? "Update" = updating a record in this table (or even inserting a record)? Or updating the table schema (migration?)? As a side note: I think `ParentCommentId` should be nullable (`int?`) because you certainly will have comments without a parent, like the very first comment to a thread.

Comment: @Slauma Sorry for the vagueness. Specifically I was talking about creating a new comment and adding it to the database. So, inserting a new row. And yes I agree with you about the int?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Slauma, you need to change `ParentCommentId` to `int?` type. Also if you want to use ForeignKeyAttribute, you need to assign it to navagation property, like below:

```
public int? ParentCommentId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentCommentId")]
public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
```

Below is an example, I'm using fluent API to configure the relationships.

`Coment` Model class:

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public String UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCommentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }

    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` class:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
           .HasOptional(c => c.ParentComment )
           .WithMany(c => c.Comments)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCommentId );
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll try this when I get back to my other computer tomorrow. I haven't seen much fluent API so I was reading here, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx). I was wondering if you had any advice on when to use fluent api and when annotations are enough?

Comment: hi @rocktheartsm4l, everything what you can configure with DataAnnotations is also possible with the Fluent API.From the viewpoint of configuration options and flexibility the Fluent API is "better".